# how to i select multiple keys using JQ

Tags: json, select, key, jq

How can `jq` extract both the `index` key and `doctype` key based on the `dynamic` attribute?:

```
{
    "index1": {
        "mappings": {
            "doctype1": {
                "dynamic": "true"
            },
            "doctype2": {
                "dynamic": "static"
            }
        }
    },
    "index2": {
        "mappings": {
            "doctype3": {
                "dynamic": "static"
            },
            "doctype4": {
                "dynamic": "true"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to give:

```
{
    "index1": {
        "doctype2": { "dynamic": "static" }
    },
    {
    "index2": {
        "doctype3": { "dynamic": "static" }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "index1": "['doctype2']",
    "index2": "['doctype3']"
}
```

I have tried:

```
jq '. | keys as $i | .[].mappings | keys as $d | $i $d'
```

but it's not even close

Comment: Which one is your expected output? Explain that clearly

Comment: Can you confirm the 2nd output is a string (instead of a JSON array)?

Comment: @oliv: Accidentally removed part of the edit

Comment: I species two outputs as I wasn't particular on the exact format/schema, just that extracting two keys was problematic. The conditional was a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these filters:

For the first output:

```
jq '[
      tostream|
      select(.[1]=="static" and (.[0]|.[-1] == "dynamic"))|
      {(.[0]|.[0]):{(.[0]|.[2]):{(.[0]|.[3]):.[1]}}}
    ]|add' file
```

And the 2nd one:

```
jq '[
      tostream|
      select(.[1]=="static" and (.[0]|.[-1] == "dynamic"))|
      {(.[0]|.[0]):[(.[0]|.[2])]}
    ]|add' file
```

Both filter relies on `tostream` function (requires at least jq version 1.5) which give the content of the input into array in a form `[path[],value]`.

The `select` function get all paths ending with `dynamic` and `static`.

The 3rd part of the filter forge the new object according to the expected output by looking up the array path.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the output in the first form:

```
map_values( .mappings
            | with_entries( select( .value.dynamic == "static" )) )
```

We use `map_values` as the input is a JSON object, and we want to retain its keys; we use `with_entries` as that makes it easy to select the keys of interest.

The above filter could easily be tweaked to yield the output in the second form, but that form is a bit weird and perhaps not-to-be-encouraged, so I won't.

Comment: `map_values` adds an empty object in case there is another object e.g. `index3` with `mappings` and `doctype` but without `"dynamic": "static"`

Comment: @oliv - Sure.  The requirements are not so clear on this and other points, but if such keys are to be omitted, that can easily be done, e.g. by post-processing.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, but I actually thought the `select` could better placed. Nice answer anyway +1.